# Install latest Version: 7.9.1 LTS sonarqube script

Tags: bash, shell, sonarqube, redhat, yum

I am looking for bash/shell script which can act as bootstrap to install latest version of Sonarqube. Below script works fine but its installing `Version 7.1 (build 11001)` version. Help me in installing Version: 7.9.1 LTS of Sonarqube.

```
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y upgrade
sudo yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk
sudo yum -y install wget nfs-utils
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/sonar.repo http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/sonar-pkg/rpm/sonar.repo
sudo yum -y install sonar
```

Output of `yum list *sonar*` is given below:-

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-136-171-208 ~]$ yum list *sonar* 
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
189 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Installed Packages
sonar.noarch                                                                                                  
7.1-1
@sonar
```

If possible provide me latest sonar.repo URL

Comment: A request for a URL is off-topic here; see #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

SonarSource [have not provided a SonarQube RPM repository since 7.1](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/is-a-native-packages-repository-still-maintained/1228/11). You could fork the original repository (now archived) or [one of it's updated clones](https://github.com/durandx/sonar-native-packages) and try to build your own distribution from there, or switch to using an alternative distribution mechanism [such as Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/).